# Does ROS allow me to get the sounds/feels/accelometer from my robot's sensors?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

? I don't see anywhere on the Website that says it does other than 3D modeling.......

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224070/does-ros-allow-me-to-get-the-sounds/feels/accelometer-from-my-robot%27s-sensors?/) by [ADVANCESSSS](https://answers.ros.org/users/25570/advancessss/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2016-01-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS has standard message types for representing sound and accelerometer readings.

If there are already ROS drivers for your robot or your sensors, they may publish the messages that you're looking for.

If there aren't ROS drivers for your robot yet, you may need to write a ROS node to retrieve the data from your sensor, convert it to a standard message, and publish it within ROS. This is usually not hard to do if you have a C/C++ library or a communication protocol for your robot.

Without knowing which robot you have, it's difficult to be more precise.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ADVANCESSSS](https://answers.ros.org/users/25570/advancessss/) on 2016-01-13**:
With OpenCV, and now ROS, I'v gotten really scared at how complex it'd be now, is there some easy way for me to buy a robot with the ROS so I only have to code my c++ and put in their library commands? I mean ROS's super-extra installation steps are just, I need it to be like OpenCV I can't do them.

**Comment by [ADVANCESSSS](https://answers.ros.org/users/25570/advancessss/) on 2016-01-13**:
Like Idk if I should get someone to set it all up for me, I need the install to be as easy as OpenCV and the library commands that I type as code with my c++ code and just that, nothing else more further deep.